# Javascript shorthand ternary operator not working when setting to variable in object literal

Tags: javascript, modernizr, object-literal

I am trying to cache variables when JS first runs, and I need to check for classes on `html` element either `.supports-no-touch` or `.no-touch` (to make sure to catch either versions depending on which version Modernizr is used).

When I run it like this,

```
window.MyScript = window.MyScript || {};
MyScript.cacheSelectors = function () {
  MyScript.cache = {
    $slideoutNavDesktop: ($('.supports-no-touch #slideoutNav') || $('.no-touch #slideoutNav'))
    // OR
    // $slideoutNavDesktop: $('.supports-no-touch #slideoutNav') ? $('.supports-no-touch #slideoutNav') : $('.no-touch #slideoutNav')
  }
};
MyScript.cacheSelectors();
console.log( MyScript.cache.$slideoutNavDesktop );
```

The result of the console.log is <s>`undefined`</s> empty jQuery object, like:

```
► [prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: ".supports-no-touch #slideoutNav"]
```

When I run the same code in console, like

```
console.log( $('.supports-no-touch #slideoutNav') || $('.no-touch #slideoutNav') );
console.log( $('.supports-no-touch #slideoutNav') ? $('.supports-no-touch #slideoutNav') : $('.no-touch #slideoutNav') );
```

I get the right element.

Also, I know that on page load, the `html` element **does** have the `.no-touch` class.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: I was getting `undefined` due to a spelling error in the variable reference.

Comment: jquery objects are always truthy

Comment: Use `$('.supports-no-touch #slideoutNav').length`

Comment: Most likely those jquery selectors will get executed when this method was getting compiled

Comment: you have no ternary operator either

Comment: @gurvinder372 - compiled?

Comment: @JaromandaX when this js code was getting compiled and loaded into the memory.

Comment: @evolutionxbox - no, because that would result in `$slideoutNavDesktop` having `$('.supports-no-touch #slideoutNav').length` - which isn't `$('.supports-no-touch #slideoutNav')`

Comment: @gurvinder372 - compiled? You can keep saying compiled, but you're always going to be wrong

Comment: @JaromandaX why? you mean it is only getting parsed and not getting compiled in true sense? then yes I would be wrong

Comment: @gurvinder372 - no, I mean, that's not even close to the reason - first comment is the reason

Comment: @JaromandaX I doubt that since he is getting  the correct value when the same code is running in the console

Comment: When I use my method (either with shorthand-if or with `||`), though the object returns `undefined` when logged to console on page load, it still works when used to trigger a hover event **but only in Chrome**, while in Firefox it comes out undefined and does Not work to trigger event.

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry my comment was incomplete. I use the length property as a check that the element exists. (See T.J. Crowder's answer)

Comment: @gurvinder372 - highly doubtful ... try this `console.log( $('non-existent-tag') || $('body') );` ... guess what is logged? ... yep ... a jQuery object with selector = `non-existent-tag`

Comment: @JaromandaX then why is OP getting `undefined` in his console?

Comment: Ohhhhhhh!  I get it lol.   A jQuery Object of "Length: 0" is truthy!! It's not "-1"!  It just doesn't contain any DOM elements... Dohh!

Comment: @gurvinder372 - OP says that ... doesn't mean it's a fact

Comment: @AndreBulatov - no ... an Object is truthy ... doesn't matter about any properties it has `console.log(!!{})` - logs true

Comment: PS:  I was getting undefined because of a dumb spelling error, leading off the last character of a stupidly long variable name.   SUPER SORRY APOLOGIES.

Comment: see how I said `doesn't mean it's a fact` :p I never tire of being right :p

Comment: ...I was really tempted to not tell you and to continue advocating for the side of my BS :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery always returns a non-`null` object reference, which is always truthy, so neither of those will work. I think the results you're seeing in the console are the result of some kind of confusion (the console can be a bit confusing).

You can use the conditional operator, but you need to check `.length`:

```
var x = $('.supports-no-touch #slideoutNav').length ? $('.supports-no-touch #slideoutNav') : $('.no-touch #slideoutNav');
```

...but that does the DOM query twice. So instead:

```
var x = $('.supports-no-touch #slideoutNav');
if (!x.length) {
    x = $('.no-touch #slideoutNav');
}
```

**But**, the simpler answer is to use a selector group and take the first (possibly only) result:

```
var x = $('.supports-no-touch #slideoutNav, .no-touch #slideoutNav').first();
```

---

**Note:** Your query suggests that you have the same ID on more than one element. That's invalid. ID values **must** be unique. So if you're going to use the above, I suggest changing the `#slideoutNav` to `.slideout-nav` or similar, and changing `id="slideoutNav"` on the elements involved to `class="slideout-nav"` (adding `slideout-nav` to their existing `class` attribute if they have one).

Comment: No duplicate IDs, I swear.  It's just a way to differentiate between mobile or desktop, depending on what the containing body class is set to by Modernizr.  Thanks for answer/solution!

Comment: @AndreBulatov: In that case, you don't need this at all, just use `$("#slideoutNav")`. :-) If you need to find out whether the `html` element has `supports-no-touch`, just `flag = $("html").hasClass("supports-no-touch")`.

Comment: Ya, my method was turning into a bigger mess each day.  Thank you.